# MySQL procedure returning wrong value (INSERT SELECT confronting)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, procedure

I'm completely new to MySQL, and have been bumping with some errors, but always I do find solutions, except for this one I can't understand how to get around it.

The following MySQL Procedure returns me a value if variable "ue" is 1 or 0 (a bunch of exists validation). The validation part (SET ue = EXISTS...) works without the rest of the code, as it should, the problem is not there. But when I do execute the command INSERT INTO SELECT, it does not work, it always return 0 as response, when it should be 1. These two lines are getting in confrontation with each other.

> INSERT INTO meetup_participation SELECT user_id, event_id FROM DUAL WHERE ue=1;
>
> SELECT ue AS response;

The procedure should add 'user id' and 'event id' into meetup_participation, and then update the row at 'users' corresponding to the user with that 'user id' to increment the 'events participated'. And it also UPDATE to increment the participation in the event with this 'event id'.

I am using the SET ue to validate things like, if user exists, if event does exists, if date of event is still valid, and if user is not already in this table. So I am passing this value as a boolean to INSERT INTO meetup_participation [...] WHERE ue = 1. After that, I do SELECT ue to inform validation returned true and procedure executed without problems.

Here is the full procedure.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `join_event`(IN `user_id` BIGINT(64), IN `event_id` INT) NOT DETERMINISTIC MODIFIES SQL DATA SQL SECURITY DEFINER
 
begin 

DECLARE ue INT;
SET ue = EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE fb_uid=user_id) AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM meetup WHERE meet_id=event_id) AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM meetup WHERE date > NOW() AND meet_id = event_id) AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM meetup WHERE meet_id = event_id AND participants <= max_participants) AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM meetup_participation WHERE fb_uid = user_id AND meet_id = event_id);

INSERT INTO meetup_participation SELECT user_id, event_id FROM DUAL WHERE ue=1; 

UPDATE users SET events_participated = events_participated + 1 WHERE fb_uid=user_id AND ue=1; 
UPDATE meetup SET participants = participants + 1 WHERE meet_id=event_id AND ue=1; 
SELECT ue AS response; 

end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's difficult to understand from the code segment which fields are coming from database tables and which are parameters passed to the procedure. It would help if you could provide the create procedure statement with the variable declarations and alias the the column names coming from the db. If the procedure is not too long edit the question to include the full procedure. Also I don't know what this two lines become in confront means, can you find another way to describe what you mean?

Comment: @P.Salmon I have edited the code for better understanding, in confront I mean, without 'INSERT INTO SELECT', it does return the right value it shoulds... Confront might not be the right way to say in english.

Comment: Your procedure does work - with the possible exceptions of SET events_participated = events_participated + 1 and SET participants = participants + 1 which need to be qualified to cater for a starting value of null - SET events_participated = ifnull(events_participated,0) + 1 and SET participants = ifnull(participants,0) + 1.

Comment: @P.Salmon This field is set to start with default value 0, but thanks for the tip! It does work, update all fields and insert the row all correctly, but my problem is with the returned value, it does always return 0 instead of 1 from 'ue' variable. When updated the question I lost the last part, when it does "SELECT ue AS response", and thats where it does fail.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue - if the select ue always returns a value of 0  then your set ue must always returns a value of 0 - the value of ue does not change between the set and the select.

Comment: That is the odd thing, when I remove the INSERT command, it does return the value of 1 or 0 accordingly to validation. But when I do re-add INSERT command it always return me 0. — I also tried with IF ELSE, removing the uncommon INSERT [..] SELECT WHERE. But the error still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The INSERT statement is executed separately from the SET ue =... statement. I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but the code makes no sense.

If you want to add records to meetup_participation based on the EXISTS tests applied to each record in the users table, you would need to apply the tests to each record in your SELECT statement as part of the INSERT.

There are also numerous syntax/grammar issues in the code as shown.

If you could provide an explanation of what you are trying to accomplish with the procedure, that might allow someone to suggest the right way to code the procedure.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know why it does not make sense... I have edited the question, maybe it is better... The code does (insert, update...) work except for returning the selected value, and the select code does works without INSERT command. What are the grammar/syntax issues? PMA does not alert me of any...

Comment: Each of the statements stands on it's own. If after the set, ue = 1, it will be equal to 1 for all records in the select part of the insert. IOW, it would insert all records from dual into meetup_participation. It will not change from one record to another in dual. Same for the two selects. You are using the value returned, not the "formula" from the set statement.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting ue will not tell you if the procedure completed without error. You should research mysql transactions and mysql error handling. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-error-handling-in-stored-procedures/ is a good starting point.

You might end up with something like this

```
drop procedure if exists p;
delimiter //

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `p`(
    IN `inue` int,
    IN `user_id` BIGINT(64),
    IN `event_id` INT
)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
MODIFIES SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
begin 

DECLARE ue INT;
declare exit handler for sqlexception
begin
    rollback;
    insert into errors (msg) select concat('error ' ,inue,',',user_id,',',event_id);
end;

set autocommit = 0;
#set ue = inue;
 SET ue = EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE fb_uid=user_id) 
    AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM meetup WHERE meet_id=event_id) 
    #AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM meetup WHERE dt > NOW() AND meet_id = event_id) 
    AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM meetup WHERE meet_id = event_id AND ifnull(participants,0) <= max_participants) 
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM meetup_participation WHERE fb_uid = user_id AND meet_id = event_id)
    ;
select ue;

if ue = 1 then

start transaction;

INSERT INTO meetup_participation SELECT user_id, event_id,user_id, event_id; 
UPDATE users SET events_participated = ifnull(events_participated,0) + 1 WHERE fb_uid=user_id = user_id; 
UPDATE meetup SET participants = ifnull(participants,0) + 1 WHERE meet_id = event_id ; 

commit;

end if;

SELECT ue AS response; 

end //
```

The error table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE `errors` (
  `msg` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Note I am not suggesting this is a solution appropriate to your site , you need to do the research and figure out what is best for you.